# Is there a way to cancel/skip a job that is waiting for approval other than rejecting it?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure Pipelines (YAML), say we got 3 stages, and the last one requires an approval. So we can review it and either approve or reject. If rejected, this shows as an error for the job and the whole pipeline execution:

```
[1. completed] --> [2. completed] --> [3. check failed: error]
```

Is there a way to skip it instead of rejecting it and if yes, how?

```
[1. completed] --> [2. completed] --> [3. skipped]
```

Answer (score 0):

True, a Rejected stage is considered an error.  But a Canceled stage is not - if it's possible to use that in your pipeline - some won't support it.  Usually to prevent these errors, I would remove the trigger (set trigger to 'false') in your yaml, so that the third stage was only runnable manually, but leaving in the 'Pre-Approvals' for said stage, so that a check-point was being recorded.